# Testing ability to "print" a class with rspec - "Print" call works in my program, but in rspec it returns nil

Tags: ruby, rspec

This is a simple problem but I'm not sure what's going wrong. I've implemented a "to_s" method in my class that prints its "@status". When I initialize an instance and print it within the script file, it works. But when I try to do the same thing with rspec, it fails and says it returned "nil." I know rspec is set up correctly because I got other tests for this class to pass.

Here's the class (cell.rb):

```
class Cell
  def initialize(status=' ')
    @status = status
  end

  def to_s
    "#{@status}"
  end
end
cell = Cell.new
print cell
```

And the test (relevant parts of cell_spec.rb):

```
describe Cell do
  before :each do
    @cell = Cell.new
  end

  it 'prints its status' do
    expect(print @cell).to eq(@cell.status)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `print` method always returns `nil`.

You would want your rspec to be like:

```
it 'prints its status' do
  expect(@cell.to_s).to eq(@cell.status)
end
```

You are not looking to test the print function, rather you are testing your `to_s`.